# Latex page as figure in word page

Tags: msword, latex-to-word

I'm wondering if it is possible to take a latex page (text+figure) and insert it as figure in a word page without affecting its quality.

I tried to do a screenshot and copy it into the word page, and I tried to convert latex to word, but the result is not good.

---

EDIT

Pdf inserted as object in word:

[image]

Thank you for your willingness.

Comment: Cut the page out of the pdf and include the pdf in Word.

Comment: Hello @Johannes_B, I forgot to say that I tried to insert the pdf page as word object, but the edges of text and figure are very bad.

Comment: The edges are bad, what does that mean? What is your final goal?

Comment: @Johannes_B see edit please.

Comment: I'd argue that this is off topic?

Comment: Hello @AndreasStorvikStrauman, why is it off topic? Only the edit is "off topic"; it's a reply to Johannes_B.

Comment: Because it's really a question about importing a pdf into word. Not really about LaTeX